# Javascript that works in Chrome but nothing else

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, syntax-error

I'm working on this addition problem worksheet and I got it working and running in Chrome but the next question button doesn't work in anything else. This is my first Javascript program. I ran it through a validator and got it down to 1 error, but commenting out that line doesn't seem to help.

Here's the whole Javascript section:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var questionTop = new Array(); //Array to store the top random number of questions
var questionBot = new Array(); //Array to store the bottom random number of questions
var answers = new Array(); //Array to store the answers the user enters
var correct = new Array(); //Array to store the correct answers
var questionMarker = 0; //Loop counter for number of times through
var correctAnswers = 0; //Counter for number of correct answers

function startQuiz() {
    questionMarker = 0;  //Function starts the quiz and resets the form
    correctAnswers = 0;  //so that the first random numbers show up and hides the start button
    document.getElementById('startButton').style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('nextQuestion').style.visibility='visible';
    document.getElementById('firstAdd').innerHTML=randomNumber();
    document.getElementById('secondAdd').innerHTML=randomNumber();
}

function randomNumber()
{
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*50) + 1; //Generates a random number between 1-50
    return number;
}

function nextQuestion()
{
    if(txtAnswer.value === "") //Check to see if they answered the question
    {
        alert("You didn't answer the question."); //Tell them they didn't
    }
    else
    {
        questionTop[questionMarker] = document.getElementById('firstAdd').innerHTML * 1; //Stores the top random number in the array
        questionBot[questionMarker] = document.getElementById('secondAdd').innerHTML * 1; //Stores the bottom random number in the array
        answers[questionMarker] = txtAnswer.value; //Stores the answer given by the user
        correct[questionMarker] = questionTop[questionMarker] + questionBot[questionMarker]; //Calculates and stores the correct answer
        if(answers[questionMarker] == correct[questionMarker]) //Checks to see if they got the answer right
        {
            alert("You got the question right!"); //Tells them so
            correctAnswers++; //Counts the correct answer for later
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Sorry that was not the correct answer." + '\n' + "You answered " + answers[questionMarker] + '\n' + "The correct answer was " + correct[questionMarker]); //Tells them the answer if they got it wrong and compares to their answer
        }
        document.getElementById('firstAdd').innerHTML=randomNumber(); //Generates new top random number
        document.getElementById('secondAdd').innerHTML=randomNumber(); //Generates new bottom random number
        txtAnswer.value = ""; //Clears the answer field
        txtCarry.value = ""; //Clears the carry field
        questionMarker++; //Increments the questionMarker so we know how many questions we've answered.
    }
    if(questionMarker == 10) //If we've answered 10 questions...
    {
        alert("You have completed the quiz!"); //The quiz is completed
        document.write("Your Answers:"); //Displays their answers
        document.write('\n' + questionTop[0] + " + " + questionBot[0] + " = " + answers[0] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[0]);
        document.write('\n' + questionTop[1] + " + " + questionBot[1] + " = " + answers[1] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[1]);
        document.write('\n' + questionTop[2] + " + " + questionBot[2] + " = " + answers[2] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[2]);
        document.write('\n' + questionTop[3] + " + " + questionBot[3] + " = " + answers[3] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[3]);
        document.write('\n' + questionTop[4] + " + " + questionBot[4] + " = " + answers[4] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[4]);
        document.write('\n' + questionTop[5] + " + " + questionBot[5] + " = " + answers[5] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[5]);
        document.write('\n' + questionTop[6] + " + " + questionBot[6] + " = " + answers[6] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[6]);
        document.write('\n' + questionTop[7] + " + " + questionBot[7] + " = " + answers[7] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[7]);
        document.write('\n' + questionTop[8] + " + " + questionBot[8] + " = " + answers[8] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[8]);
        document.write('\n' + questionTop[9] + " + " + questionBot[9] + " = " + answers[9] + "  Correct Answer is: " + correct[9]);
        document.write('\n' + "You got " + correctAnswers + " answers right out of 10."); //Shows how many answers they got right
        document.write('\n' + "You got " + correctAnswers*10 + "% of the questions right."); //Calculates their percent right
        document.write('\n' + '<button id="newQuiz" type="button" onclick="window.location.reload()">New Quiz</button>'); //Creates new button to reload the screen and start again
    }
}

</script>
```

It's located on the web here:
http://www.innogeek.com/java/index.html
The code is in an iFrame at http://www.innogeek.com/java/frame.html

Comment: Thats a lot of code there to debug. Could you narrow it down for us?

Comment: You don't seem to define `txtAnswer` anywhere..

Comment: Added the txtAnswer, but now the game never triggers the questionMarker == 10 so the game never ends. It also appears to still not work in Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `nextQuestion()` to:

```
function nextQuestion()
{
    var txtAnswer = document.getElementById('txtAnswer'); //<-- ADD THIS
    var txtCarry = document.getElementById('txtCarry'); //<-- AND THIS

    if(txtAnswer.value === "") //Check to see if they answered the question
    {
        alert("You didn't answer the question."); //Tell them they didn't
    }
...
}
```

Your issue was you were not defining the `txtAnswer` variable before you used it.

Some browsers will map DOM IDs to Javascript variables automatically (I believe IE does this as well), but you can't really count on that working.

Comment: Got there one min before me :)

Comment: @KevinAnthonyOppegaardRose - You probably took too long answering the 2nd grade math problems :)

Comment: Unfortunately now in IE it never triggers the questionMarket == 10. I changed it to >= 10, but it never triggers it and completes the game.

Comment: Same problem - Only `txtCarry` is undefined as well.  Same solution.

Comment: Thanks Mike. It triggers but doesn't write the answers after completion. The button in Firefox doesn't work at all. I'm assuming my answers never get stored in the array properly?

Comment: I suggest stepping through it with a debugger such as Firebug or Visual Studio and figure out what's going on, there's only so much we can assist you with.  I tried it in both IE7 (yea yea, work computer) and FF9 and things seem to be working as expected.

Comment: To see the answers, you have to convert all `'\n'`s to `'<BR>'` in `document.write`s

Comment: You also might have better luck changing `document.getElementById('firstAdd').innerHTML * 1` to `parseInt(document.getElementById('firstAdd').innerHTML)`

Comment: It appears to be working in Firefox now. Thanks for your help. The only problem I'm having is in IE 9 where the only thing it displays at the end is "Your Answers:" with no answers after. Firefox and Chrome work except for the new lines after each set of answers.

Comment: IE has a habit of just exiting a function when it hits a script error.  I'd step through it under a debugger and make sure each value is what you expect it to be.  There are probably many good tutorials online about using the IE9 debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You have not declared the `txtAnswer` variable before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there's no defined variable called `txtAnswer`. I suppose that Chrome maps DOM elements with id to variables with the same name (which is a behaviour you cannot rely on).
I suggest yout to add this line to begin your `nextQuestion` function :

```
var txtAnswer = document.getElementById("txtAnswer");
```